# GAE: Identify GAE application in Firewall by URL Fetch Host header

Tags: google-app-engine, firewall, devops

I have a server that is behind a firewall (WAF - Web Application Firewall)
I'm sending a request to that server from GAE using URL Fetch.
I want to configure the firewall to accept requests only if they are coming from my GAE application.

Any Ideas?

I was thinking about the Host header of GAE but I don't know how it looks like. Maybe all requests are coming from the same domain and I can block all requests that are not coming from this domain?

Answer (score -1):

You may be able to use the `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` header mentioned in the [request headers documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/outbound-requests#request_headers), which is controlled by GAE infra:

> For security reasons, the following headers cannot be modified by the
>   application:
>
> - Content-Length
> - Host
> - Vary
> - Via
> - X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid
> - X-Forwarded-For
> - X-ProxyUser-IP

I don't know how the value for such header looks like, but you can create a test urlfetch request to a server outside the firewall and find out by inspection of the test request on that server.

You might want to combine such check with a source domain check against `appengine.com` or your own custom domain if you use one for added security.